# how i convert dateTimePickerValue type to dateTime type

Tags: c#

```
DateTime strat=new DateTime();   

strat=dateTimePickerStart.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

how i can covert the type of the dateTimePicker value to dateTime type

Comment: A `DateTimePicker.Value`'s type **is** DateTime...hence the name.  That code is (needlessly) converting to string.  `DateTime strat = dateTimePickerStart.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your dateTimePicker's value to a string which can't be assigned to a variable of type DateTime.

Options:

```
strat=dateTimePickerStart.Value;
```

or if you want to format the date as you have shown, it could be parsed:

```
strat=DateTime.Parse(dateTimePickerStart.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

however, to remove the time component this would be better:

```
strat=dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date;
```